# Adjust the size of accesory plots and margins in levelplot in R

Tags: levelplot

I am trying to adjust the plotting of a raster in [rasterVis](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/). However, I get way too large blank spaces and cannot adjust the width of the legend bar or the histograms. I also tried the tutorials here on the [main page of rasterVis](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis) but my plots never fill up the window.
I also tried restarting the device and delete all the previous plots.

Any work around? Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

raster_data <- raster(matrix(1:25, nrow = 5, ncol = 5))

levelplot(raster_data, col.regions = gray.colors(256),
          par.settings = list(layout.heights = list(hist = c(0.1, 0.9))))
```